# How to exclude standard errors from stargazer table?

Tags: r-markdown, stargazer

Amazing R gurus,

I am just wondering if there is any way to exclude standard errors from stargazer table.

Here is a quick reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Test regression"
output: html_document
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cashe = TRUE)

rm(list=ls())
library(stargazer)
library(ggplot2)

```


```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

fit <- lm(price ~ carat + table + x + y + z, data = diamonds)

stargazer(fit, title="Diamonds Regression",
          single.row = TRUE, type ="html", header = FALSE, df=FALSE, digits=2, se = NULL)

```
````

I would like to see results without standard error like shown in the following screenhsot.

[image]

Your time and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to achieve the same thing, and found the `report` argument in the [`stargazer` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer), wich can be used to control the elements shown (and the order) in the output table. 
If used like this:

```
fit <- lm(price ~ carat + table + x + y + z, data = diamonds)

stargazer(fit, title="Diamonds Regression",
          single.row = TRUE, 
          type ="html", 
          report = "vc*", 
          header = FALSE, 
          df=FALSE, 
          digits=2, 
          se = NULL
)
```

It produces the desired output without the need to capture the output first (or any other additional code).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
fit <- lm(price ~ carat + table + x + y + z, data = diamonds)
mytab <- capture.output(stargazer(fit, title="Diamonds Regression",
                        single.row = TRUE, type ="html", header = FALSE, df=FALSE,
                        digits=2, 
                        apply.se = function(x) { 0 }))

cat(paste(gsub("\\(0.00\\)", "", mytab), collapse = "\n"), "\n")
```
````

We first capture the output of `stargazer` and suppress automatic printing. In stargazer we set all standard errors to be 0 (makes the following replacement more failsave). Lastly, we print the output and replace these standard errors.

[image]

Comment: smart workaround; not very easy for everyone to get it straight. Thanks!

Comment: When I tried this, the significance stars got messed up and all turned to ***. Any idea how to keep those correct?

Comment: For me the code above still produces the result seen in the screenshot.